# What kind of a generative model is an RNN?

Tags: neural-networks, recurrent-neural-network, generative-models

Given the taxonomy of generative models as presented by Ian Goodfellow in Tutorial on Generative Adversarial Networks (https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.00160), in what branch do we put the family of RNNs?

Comment: The taxonomy does not depend too much on the basic components (dense, Conv, RNN) used within the architecture, so an answer would be: "any".

Comment: I see, but when the mode of operation is that we have a sequence of tokens and we are trying to predict the next token given the previous tokens?

Comment: what is an 'RNN'? If I knew, I would probably edit your post and be silently annoyed about people who use abbreviations without explaining them. But I don't know what it means

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As Michael M mentions, the architecture is mostly independent of the type of generative model.

But in the *most common use-case*, RNNs are used for language modeling by decomposing $P(x)$ into $P(x_0)\prod_i P(x_i|x_{<i})$ and modeling each condition probability via neural network, which falls into the "tractable density" category.

There has also been work on recurrent VAEs (falling into the variational category) and RNN-GANs.